# How to read certificate from smart card via python?

Tags: python, smartcard, wincrypt, pyscard

I have a Smart Card (actually USB Token) with some certificate and keys written on it. Now I need to retrieve this certificate using python on Windows. How can it be achieved?

I had a look on `pyscard` package but it seems too low-level and probably not a most simple way of doing this. But if you know that low-level answer then your help will be appreciated.
Seems like `CryptAcquireContext` function from pywin32 (win32crypt) allow me to use private key from smart card for encryption purposes but I cannot get the certificate itself.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found an answer myself though. Hope it will help someone:
Usually smart card manufacturers provide a library (`.so` or `.dll`) implementing [PKCS#11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_11) standard.
There are several solutions which you can use to communicate with your smart card via this library. Such as: [pkcs11-tool](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pkcs11-tool) (CLI interface), [PyKCS11](https://github.com/LudovicRousseau/PyKCS11) (python wrapper).

Here is an example how it could be achieved with PyKCS11:

```py
from asn1crypto import x509
from PyKCS11 import *

pkcs11 = PyKCS11Lib()
pkcs11.load('<MANUFACTURER_LIBRARY_PATH>')
# get slot value via pkcs11.getSlotList(tokenPresent=False). Usually it's 0
session = pkcs11.openSession(slot, CKF_SERIAL_SESSION | CKF_RW_SESSION)
session.login('<SMART_CARD_PIN_CODE>')
result = []
certs = session.findObjects([(CKA_CLASS, CKO_CERTIFICATE)])
for cert in certs:
    cka_value, cka_id = session.getAttributeValue(cert, [CKA_VALUE, CKA_ID])
    cert_der = bytes(cka_value)
    cert = x509.Certificate.load(cert_der)
    result.append(cert)
print(result)
```

This way I was able to list certificates on smart card both on Linux and Windows

Comment: I am trying to create a python script which uses a smart card authentication to login on a website https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60112869/authentication-on-website-using-smart-card-in-python . may be you can help me there?

Comment: Using a SCR3310 reader and HID Global Active Client on windows, I found my manufacturer lib path at `C:\Program Files\HID Global\ActivClient\acpkcs211.dll`